# Pop-Up Window on page load

Tags: php, javascript, popup, onload

I need to have a pop-up window displayed when a page loads.  What's happening is this.  After an order is placed the user is redirected to their index page (main log-in page for the account)  when they are redirected to the index page, I need a pop-up window to display on the page load that says something like "Your order for $variable has been saved".  The $variable is defined on the previous page (where they are coming from) and I need that to carry over so I can display it in the pop-up box.  Then once they click on "Ok" in the pop-up box, they are at the main page like always.

I have used a java popup box before on this project, but I am unsure of how to do one with these requirements.  If there are any other/better ways to do this I am open to ideas.  The layout of how this needs to work is below:

Client is logged into their account -> Order.php Page (Place an order) -> redirected to their member-index.php page (Pop-up needs to load on page load, and only when it comes from the order.php page)

Thanks!

Comment: are you using a javascript library (jQuery, Dojo, Mootools)? Plain javascript?

Comment: Is there a reason why an order confirmation page won't work? You might want to take a look at how Amazon, Dell, etc. handle this scenario and consider redefining the workflow.

Comment: If the objective is to inform the user that an action has been successfully executed, consider something like jQuery's show() and hide() to display visible confirmation for a short time - or even a lightbox-style div.  Pop up windows (new browser windows) can be a bit of a nightmare to manage, as they can "pop-under" when the user touches the main window - causing confusion.

Comment: Do you mean [Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), or [JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)? The two are **very different.**

Comment: I retag:ed the question. Can't see a trace of java, so changed from java to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from what I understand this would be the best match for you.

On previous page save a cookie (source http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

createookie("prevData", prevData, 30);
```

Then on the page you want the popup to appear (I suggest using an alert) (Note: you need the cookie code available on this page as well):

```
var prevData =  readCookie("prevData");
if(prevData != null){
    alert("Your order for " + prevData + " has been saved");
    eraseCookie("prevData");
}
```

this could be in `<body onLoad="code">` or simply a script in the header or anywhere really.

Comment: The code to create the cookie, where do I put that on my previous page? In the header, body?

Answer (score 0):

You can't force a popup page to open upon page load; browsers won't do that anymore. You can create a "fake" popup window by just positioning an element in the middle of the screen and decorating it so that it looks kind-of like a window. Various JavaScript libraries provide such "dialog" facilities.

Answer (score 0):

`
function showpopup() {

```
            var findString = /order.php/gi;
            var referringURL = document.referrer;
            var data = getQuerystring('variable');
            if(referringURL.match(findString)) {
                var windowprops = "left=50,top=50,width=500,height=500";
                var preview = window.open("http://google.com", "preview", windowprops);
                preview.document.write(data);
            } else {
                alert("Not order.php "+data);
            }
        }

        function getQuerystring(key, default_) {
            if (default_==null) default_="";
            key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
            var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
            if(qs == null)
                return default_;
            else
                return qs[1];
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="showpopup()">
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean javascript. You may want to do this

```
<body onLoad="popup()">
```

Any code in the "onLoad" event should fire once the html is loaded.
If you are using Jquery, it should look like this

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    popup();
});
```

You can pass your variable into the popup function.

Comment: Just a note, `"document"` should not be in quotes, it should be `$(document).ready()`, or the shortest form, only `$(popup);` overall.